# PHP WebSocket server stops working after a while

Tags: phpwebsocket

I'm running a version of Lemmingzshadow's PHP websocket server.  It runs without problem for a few hours, sometimes even days, with several users connecting/disconnecting to it.  Then, for no apparent reason, it stops accepting new connections.  It's still running, and it's still handling the *connected* users properly, but no *new* users can connect.

When a user tries to connect, I get this in the log file:

```
PHP Warning:  fwrite(): 1425 is not a valid stream resource in /server/includes/Socket.php on line 127
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?  Again, everything runs fine for a while, then... it doesn't.